# Android convert T00:00:00.000Z date to simple readable date format

Tags: android, date

How can I convert this format of date as `2016-12-02T00:00:00.000Z` to simple format such as for example `2016-12-02 12:00:00`?

I can not find any solution about that on google and this site, i get this format from web service.

This is my solution, but it doesn't work correctly and I got error:

```
Method threw 'java.text.ParseException' exception.
```

my code:

```
ISO8601 df = new ISO8601();
if (!channel.getString("createdAt").equals("0000-00-00 00:00:00") && channel.getString("createdAt").length() > 0) {
    Calendar ca        = df.toCalendar("2016-12-02T00:00:00.000Z");
    String   createdAt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss").format(df.toCalendar(channel.getString("createdAt")).getTimeInMillis());
    info.setCreated_at(createdAt);
}
```

`ISO8601` class to convert `ISO 8601` date

```
public final class ISO8601 {
    /**
     * Transform Calendar to ISO 8601 string.
     */
    public static String fromCalendar(final Calendar calendar) {
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                .format(date);
        return formatted.substring(0, 22) + ":" + formatted.substring(22);
    }

    /**
     * Get current date and time formatted as ISO 8601 string.
     */
    public static String now() {
        return fromCalendar(GregorianCalendar.getInstance());
    }

    /**
     * Transform ISO 8601 string to Calendar.
     */
    public static Calendar toCalendar(final String iso8601string)
            throws ParseException {
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        String   s        = iso8601string.replace("Z", "+00:00");
        try {
            s = s.substring(0, 22) + s.substring(23);  // to get rid of the ":"
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new ParseException("Invalid length", 0);
        }
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(s);
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return calendar;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is this exception thrown?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 on this line as `    String   createdAt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss").format(df.toCalendar(channel.getString("createdAt")).getTimeInMillis());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 String  createdAt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(df.toCalendar(channel.getString("createdAt")).getTimeInMillis());
```

here is an example:

```
String string = "2016-12-02T00:00:00.000Z";
String defaultTimezone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
Date date = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")).parse(string.replaceAll("Z$", "+0000"));

Log.i("string: " + string);
Log.i("defaultTimezone: " + defaultTimezone);
Log.i("date: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")).format(date));
```

Comment: happy to help..@NaveedAhmad